# Можно ли вынести код для яндекс карты в отдельный файл? JS

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Собственно вопрос в том, чтобы код инициализации карты вынести в отдельный файл, а не оставлять его в теге  в основном файле. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

Comment: да это возможно

Answer (score 1):

У Вас к примеру `main.js` который подключался через

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

теперь вы его хотите разделить на 2 части. Делайте так

```
<script src="main.chunk.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.chunk.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Не забываем что файл загружается и выполняется. Так что места где вы определяете функции классы и все такое прочеее подгружать раньше их использования.

Код инициализации можно вынести в отдельную функцию. Которую можно будет вызвать после загрузки DOM.

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли (или я не совсем понял). Яндекс карты подключаются через тег <script> со стороннего ресурса. Если вынести код в отдельный файл, то из него не будет видно объекта ymaps и других, потому что они объявлены через тег <script> в index.php

Comment: А ну тогда грузите js и кидаете код в ваш файл. А по хорошему лучше этого не делать

Comment: То есть лучше писать код прямо в index.php?

Comment: Пишите код как обычно разделенный по кускам и подгруженный по необходимости